# How can I prevent git corruption on linux virtual machine?

Tags: windows, git, virtualbox, corruption, smb

I have a virtual machine (Virtual Box) on a Windows host running Linux on the guest.
I have a git repo on the client with file sharing set up with Samba in such a way that it's in my Network Locations.
I run SourceTree as my git client from my Windows host to affect the repo on the VM.

The issue is that every once in a while, the git objects on my guest get corrupted. I have already found (and keep finding) ways to fix the git repo after it's corrupted. I have fixed it, and it works. The issue is that the fix removes my uncommitted changes so I have to back up every time.

My question is, how, if possible, can I PREVENT the corruption of those git objects?

It should be noted that:

- I don't force-shut down the VM.
- I have tried turning off auto-refresh in Source-Tree.
- I am aware that I can back up the git files at the end of every work session and avoid losing progress like that but that's annoying.

I am open to any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Working with two different git executables (one for Windows and one for Linux) on the same repository sounds like a bad idea.

Git is by design a distributed VCS, so you can take advantage of that. Just have one clone of the repository in your Windows filesystem, and one in your Linux VM. then have a bare repo (`git init --bare`) on your Linux VM where you can push your work and pull work from the other repo. Use `ssh` from the Windows host to push changes, not samba. Be aware that while it is possible to directly push between two non-bare repositories, it is not recommended (for example, you cannot push to the current branch of a non-bare repository).

If, by any chance, you have access to a web-based git service (GitHub, gogs, GitLab, …), you can also use that for pushing and pulling.

Comment: I am not working with two different git executables.

I can not commit and push every time I make a change because the repository would be unreadable on bitbucket.

Comment: Why do you have your repo inside the VM then?

Comment: While the setup is strange, I am doing development on that environment from the host rather than having the files on the host. I believe I state in the question anyway that I use SourceTree in the host to manage the guest's git repo.

Comment: Well your setup surely is strange and begs for errors. Have you tried putting the repo on the host instead and mounting it as shared folder in the VM?

Comment: I'm not down-voting this answer, but it's certainly not an answer to the very reasonable question. For the record, we are having the same problem and we are Linux only - running latest version of VirtualBox and git.

Comment: @hansfn Only if you assume there is a better answer. A [thread at Atlassian's forums](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/Source-tree-corrupts-git-index-file-on-smb-share/qaq-p/30396) similarly concludes not to use git over SMB (but hints that this is a SourceTree-specific issue), so your options basically seem to a) not share the repo via SMB or b) not use SourceTree.

Comment: @flyx I was actually trying to edit my comment when I discovered that this question was specific to using Git (in Windows) with the repository located on a Samba share in the virtual machine. I was too slow and couldn't edit. In my/our case we only use Git in the virtual machine and the relevant directory is private to the VM - not a shared folder or any Samba involved. Sorry about the useless comment.